# A not semisimple representation of $S_3$ over $k^3$ with $k$ a field of characteristic 3.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 3. Then we can naturally define the representation $\rho : S_3 \to GL(k^3)$ such that $\rho(\sigma)(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (x_{\sigma_1},x_{\sigma_2}, x_{\sigma_3})$. Clearly, $W = \text{Span}_k \lbrace (1,1,1) \rbrace$ is a subrepresentation beacuse is a $\rho(\sigma)$ invariant sub-space for all $\sigma \in S_3$. Show that $W$ is contained in all nonzero subrepresentation of $(k^3,\rho)$.

Let $0 \neq U \subset k^3$ a subrepresentation of $(k^3,\sigma)$.

Suppouse $\dim(U) = 1$, then $U = \text{Span}_k\lbrace(u_1,u_2,u_3)\rbrace$. Let $\sigma = (i \hspace{2mm} j)$ and $l \neq i,j$. Then, $u_i = \lambda u_j$,  $u_j = \lambda u_i$,  $u_l = \lambda u_l$. The last equation sates that $\lambda = 1$ and $u_i = u_j$. Since $\sigma$ is an arbitrary transposition, then we conclude that $u_1 = u_2 = u_3$ and $U = W$.

I'm having problems when $\dim(U) = 2$, because now all vector in $U$ under $\rho(\sigma)$ is a linear combination of two vectors and not only one, I don't even know how to start. However, I have the hunch that there is not a subrepresentation of dimension 2. I appreciate any hint :)

Comment: In all characteristics there is the zero-sum subrepresentation
$$V=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in k^3\mid x_1+x_2+x_3=0\}.$$
I leave it to you to figure out how the relation of $V$ and $W=\langle(1,1,1)\rangle$ is exceptional exactly in characteristic three.

Comment: Mind you, are you sure about the definition of $\rho$? We can think of the vectors as functions from the index set $\{1,2,3\}$ to the field $k$. The group $S_3$ acts on the index set from the left. so unless you use the inverse, it will act on the functions from the right. In other words, I think it should read
$$\sigma\cdot(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},x_{\sigma^{-1}(2)},x_{\sigma^{-1}(3)}).$$

Comment: (cont'd) For example, if $(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(4,5,6)$, then the 2-cycle $(12)$ interchanges the first two coordinates, the 2-cycle $(13)$ the first and the last. Therefore
$$(13)\cdot((12)\cdot(4,5,6))=(13)\cdot(5,4,6)=(6,4,5).$$
As $(13)(12)=(123)$, this should be equal to $(123)\cdot(4,5,6)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $U$ is 2-dimensional, it has a basis $\{u,v\}$. Naïvely all we can say about them is their coordinates $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ and $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ and $v\neq0, u\neq \lambda v$. But a little bit of linear algebra saves a lot of tedium.

Since the transposition $\tau=(2\,3)$ satisfies $\tau^2=e$, we know that $\rho(\tau)$ acting on $U$ has minimal polynomial dividing $X^2-1$. This splits completely into distinct factors $(X+1)(X-1)$ over $k$ and therefore is diagonalizable, that is, it admits an eigenbasis. Hence we can take $u$ and $v$ to be eigenvectors of $\rho(\tau)$, with eigenvalues for $u$ and $v$ being $\pm 1$.

Then $u_2=\pm u_3$ and $v_2=\pm v_3$. Note that neither of these can be zero, or else $(*,0,0)\in U$ and therefore by applying $\sigma=(1\, 2\, 3)$, all of $k^3$ is in $U$, but $U$ is supposed to be 2-dimensional.

**Case I.** If $u_1=v_1=0$ then we may scale so that $u_2=v_2=1$. But since $u\neq v$ we must have that $u_3=-1$ and $v_3=1$. In particular $v=(1,1,1)$, so $W\subseteq U$.

**Case II.** If $u_1\neq 0$ and $v_1\neq 0$ then we may scale so that $u_1=v_1=1$. Now we consider $\rho(\sigma)u=au+bv$, or in expanded form,
\begin{align*}
u_2 &=a+b \\
\pm u_2 &=au_2+bv_2 \\
1 &=\pm(au_2+bv_2)
\end{align*}
The signs in the last two equations are the same, and thus $u_2=1$. Similarly $v_2=1$. So as before, $(1,1,1)\in U$.

**Case III.** Otherwise, without loss of generality: $u_1=1$, and $v_1=0$ and $v_2=1$. The above equations still hold, so that $u_2=1$. Note that $u_3=-1$ is impossible: if $v_3=-1$ also, then $u-v=e_1$, but if instead $v_3=1$, then
$$u-\rho(\sigma^{-1})v=(1,1,-1)-(1,1,0) = -e_3.$$
Either statement contradicts that $U$ is 2-dimensional. Therefore, $u_3$ and so $u=(1,1,1)\in U$, as desired.

[ Note that Jyrki's example falls in the final subcase: $u=(1,1,1)$ and $v=(0,1,-1)$ is permitted, and $u+v=(1,2,0)=(1,-1,0)$. ]